# Stream.max(Integer::max) : Unexpected result

Tags: java, java-8, compare, max, java-stream

I'm studying for [1z0-809 : Java SE 8 Programmer II](https://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=5001&get_params=p_exam_id:1Z0-809) using Enthuware's mocktests.

Encountering this question.

> ```
> List<Integer> ls = Arrays.asList(3,4,6,9,2,5,7);
>
> System.out.println(ls.stream().reduce(Integer.MIN_VALUE, (a, b)->a>b?a:b)); //1
> System.out.println(ls.stream().max(Integer::max).get()); //2
> System.out.println(ls.stream().max(Integer::compare).get()); //3
> System.out.println(ls.stream().max((a, b)->a>b?a:b)); //4
> ```
>
> Which of the above statements will print 9?

Answer is

> 1 and 3

But there is something else. I don't get why

```
System.out.println(ls.stream().max(Integer::max).get()); // PRINTS 3
```

---

I tried to debug it using `peek` but it doesn't help me understanding.

I tried to sort `ls` using `Integer::max` and `Integer::compare`

```
ls.sort(Integer::max);     // [3, 4, 6, 9, 2, 5, 7]
ls.sort(Integer::compare); // [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
```

Of course, I get the fact that `Integer::max` is not a Comparator, hence it has the same signature of one.
For me, `max` should be `7` in the first case since it is the last element like when I sorted with `Integer::compare`

Could someone break it down to something simple?

Comment: I did not get how `stream.max` worked while given a `Comparator`. That's a bit different

Comment: How is it different at all? As long as the comparator obeys the contract...

Comment: @fge This one does not obey the contract. That's why it is confusing. Check Tunaki's answer.

Comment: But you said it yourself: `Integer::max` is not a comparator. So what is the problem? Note that the runtime mechanism only checks whether the _signature_ matches; it won't check the "correctness of behavior" (it cannot, really).

Comment: @fge First of all, there is no problem. I was curious about why the result was 3. I didn't say it was a correct comparaison. I didn't even speak about the correctness of the behavior at all since the correct answer wasn't 2, it was 1 and 3. I just wanted to know **WHY** the output was 3 and **HOW** did it become 3. :) That's it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Integer.max(a, b)` will return the greater value of the given `a` and `b`. If you use that result somehow as a comparator, a positive value returned will be regarded as meaning that `a > b` so `a` will be kept.

The first two elements are 3 and 4. Both are positive. `Integer.max(3, 4) = 4 > 0`. So you're effectively saying that `3 > 4` with such a comparator, so 3 is kept. Then, the same goes for the rest: `Integer.max(3, 6) = 6 > 0`, so 3 is considered the max, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much that's what I needed ! So it keeps the max of the previous ones in memory and goes on the next ones until the end.

Comment: Actually the result of this case is unspecified. You're feeding the `.max` with broken comparator, so you can get any result. It's not specified how exactly `.max` will compare the input.

Comment: @TagirValeev Isn't it possible to predict the output?

Comment: @YassinHajaj, it's possible looking into concrete implementation. But you cannot guarantee that next java update (even minor) will not change the implementation.

Answer (score 11):

You need to replace

```
.max(Integer::max)
```

with

```
.max(Integer::compare)
```

---

The problem here is that the abstract method `compare` is declared to return an `int` value and that is also satisfied by the signature of `Integer.max` along with method `Integer.compare` in the `Integer` class, hence the representation `Integer::max` is inferred as a valid `Comparator`. Though the compare method is expected to be implemented such as it:

> Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first
>   argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

In your current scenario, the code always ends up returning a positive value (given the input) and therefore the first element in comparison is considered to be greater always and thus returned accordingly.

Comment: Instead of `.max(Integer::compare)`, I’d use `.max(Comparator.naturalOrder())`, to avoid the redundant creation of a new `Comparator`. Or use `int i = map.keySet().stream() .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt) .max() .getAsInt();` in the first place…

Answer (score 6):

The contract of a comparator method (on arguments `first`, `second`) is:

- return 0 if `first` equals `second`
- return negative value if `first < second`
- return positive value if `first > second`

The `max` method with only positive values will always return a positive value. When interpreting the return value according to the comparator contract, a positive value means `first > second`. As a result, the ordering of items will not change, they appear to be "ordered".

Answer (score 6):

This is unbelievably confusing.

We are trying use `Integer::max` as a comparator. Since all the numbers in the question are positive, the answer is always interpreted as meaning that the first argument of `compare(a, b)` is "greater" than the second.

One quirk of `Collections.sort` is that when you have a list `[a, b]`, the method is programmed in such a way that it is `compare(b, a)` that is called, rather than `compare(a, b)` (which would seem more sensible). Hence if `compare` returns a positive number, it looks like `b > a`, so the list does not need sorting.

That is why `list.sort` does nothing.

However it just happens that `Stream.max` is programmed the other way around, i.e. the first comparison is `compare(3, 4)`, so it looks like `3` is the maximum.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem at all. Comparison is a _qualitative_ operation, not a _quantitative_ operation. If I compare 234 to 2, the result of the comparison may be 232, 1, 99392 or 98; it _does not matter_. And neither does the order in which arguments are called.

Comment: @fge It does matter, because `max` does not meet the contract for `compare`. Imagine you try to sort [a, b]. If you do compare(a, b) and get a positive answer, it means that a > b so you need to swap. If you do compare(b, a) and get a positive answer it means that b > a so you do not need to swap. I can assure you that I am correct.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Thanks for the answer ! It is indeed really confusing. Was just curious about the result :).

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't answer the question, a possible solution to your problem would be:

```
try{
    int i = map.values().stream().mapToInt(e -> e).max().getAsInt();
}catch(NoSuchElementException e)
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The `mapToInt(e -> e)` method uses a lambda expression to transform every element in the stream to a integer value and returns a `IntStream` where `max()` method can then be called.
Note that `max()` returns an `OptionalInteger` and so a `getAsInt()` or a `orElse(0)` method call is nedeed.

You can take a look at the docs for a more in-depth answer: [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#max--), [OptionalInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html#getAsInt--)

Comment: Fine solution.Another option is `String maxId = Collections.max(map.keySet(), Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::parseInt));`.